# How to apply scoping on associations in Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-admin

I am newbie to Ruby,  Rails and Rails Admin. I came to know about scopes in ActiveRecord. I want to apply scoping to associations at the time of editing a record using the Admin interface.

Example: I have a model named Post. A post is created by some User. A user can be an admin or a normal user distinguished by relational column *is_admin*. At the time of creating/editing a post using the Rails Admin interface, we have to allow selection from normal user list.

I have created scope normal_users for ActiveRecord User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :normal_users, -> { where(is_admin: false) }
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  rails_admin do
    edit do
        configure :user do
          # _____________ ? what goes here so that only normal users are listed.
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Now how can I use this  'normal_users' scope in the belongs_to association in the Post so that the dropdown for the field user in the Post resource  lists only the normal users.

I have seen examples filtering associations/scopes in Rails. But I do not know how to use/configure this in Rails Admin.

Comment: `user.normal_user`

Comment: But when I search by typing in the field I get admins as well. I expect filtering and scoping to work together.

Comment: in your console try `User.normal_users` and see what you get, anyway I thought the question was how to apply scoping, and not if your scope is returning the correct response

Comment: Running `Users.normal_users` in the rails console is returning only normal users. It seems scoping is working. But I need to get this work in conjunction with filterable dropdown  in the Rails admin.

Comment: How about adding a `where` to the `Users.normal_users`.

Comment: How to fill in the the value typed in the text field in the Rails Admin in the where  query?  Is there a way to access the value of the field ? Will that query run every time I type something in that field. Please guide me if I am missing anything as I am a newbie to this Ruby world.